# Weird behavior on WHERE and GROUP BY statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I'm defining from which table the column I'm using is, on the WHERE/GROUP BY statements, it has a different result if I explicit say from which table the column is. Even if the other table doesn't have that column. Ex:

Table_A:

| ID | Date | something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-11 | "string1" |
| 2 | 2021-09-12 | "string2" |
| 3 | 2021-09-13 | "string3" |
| 4 | 2021-09-14 | "string4" |

Table_B:

| ID | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "category1" |
| 2 | "category2" |
| 3 | "category3" |
| 4 | "category4" |

This query returns empty:

```
WITH Table_B AS (
      SELECT
        ID,
        IFNULL(category, "-") as category,
      FROM bigger_table_B_with_repeated_IDS
      QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY time_column ASC) = 1
)

SELECT A.*, B.Category 
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Date = "2021-09-11" AND B.Category = "category1"
```

But this query returns:

```
WITH Table_B AS (
      SELECT
        ID,
        IFNULL(category, "-") as category,
      FROM bigger_table_B_with_repeated_IDS
      QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY time_column ASC) = 1
)

SELECT A.*, B.Category 
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Date = "2021-09-11" AND Category = "category1"
```

| ID | Date | something | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-11 | "string1" | "category1" |

**EDIT [resolved]:**

I found the problem: the table "bigger_table_B_with_repeated_IDS" had two categorys with exactly the same time stamp (which was an error from another person) and the QUALIFY OVER had an ambiguity. Depending of the order that the query were executed, the QUALIFY OVER returned an different row.

Comment: Both queries in your question are identical.

Comment: Sry, copy and paste... Already edited

Comment: Generally you don't want to filter on the inner table after doing an outer join. This sounds like an unusual behavior that is probably unique to BigQuery.

Comment: Then should I define an intermediary table and filter after?

Comment: Well filtering after the outer join defeats the purpose of doing the outer join in the first place. I can't imagine you'd get different results with an inner join.

Comment: Wdym? I have to apply the filter with a column that olny existis in table B to table A, but values from table B that don't have a matching ID on A should be ignored. Maybe the example isn't clear, but not all ID's necessarily match.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: I added the way I define the "table_B" on the example, maybe you can reproduce this way